# Foreign key associations in Rails with Postgres array possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-postgresql

Given the following `Tweet`:

```
# db/schema.rb
create_table "tweets", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "project_id",            null: false
  t.integer  "author_id",             null: false
  t.integer  "twitter_id",            limit: 8, null: false
  t.text     "text"
  t.integer  "in_reply_to_status_id", limit: 8
  t.integer  "previous_tweet_ids",    limit: 8, array: true
end

add_index "tweets", ["previous_tweet_ids"], name: "index_tweets_on_previous_tweet_ids", using: :gin
add_index "tweets", ["project_id", "author_id"], name: "index_tweets_on_project_id_and_author_id", using: :btree
add_index "tweets", ["project_id", "twitter_id"], name: "index_tweets_on_project_id_and_twitter_id", unique: true, using: :btree
add_index "tweets", ["project_id"], name: "index_tweets_on_project_id", using: :btree
```

`previous_tweet_ids` is a Postgres array that stores the `twitter_id` of all previous tweets. I'm looking for a way to efficiently retrieving the previous tweets for a set of tweets. This is what I'm currently doing:

```
# app/models/tweet.rb
class Tweet
  def previous_tweets
    @previous_tweets ||= project.tweets.where(twitter_id: previous_tweet_ids)
  end

  def future_tweets
    @future_tweets ||= project.tweets.where('previous_tweet_ids && ARRAY[?]', twitter_id)
  end
end
```

Is there a way to transform these `previous_tweets` and `future_tweets` methods into an ActiveRecord association, to use ActiveRecord's eager loading like `Tweet.incoming.includes(:previous_tweets, :future_tweets)`?

Thanks for any pointers in advance.